# WL methods not getting called in MobileFirst 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to call WL worklight methods in Mobilefirst 8.0. But none of the methods called. I have tried WLResourceRequest, WL.Client.Environment etc for calling adapter methods. 
    Code Snippet:

```
alert("Calling adapter");                //printed
var url = "/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed1";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
alert("Called adapter");                 //Not Printed
```

Here, `alert("Called adapter");`  not executed. Please let me know if I have to include some worklight library or need to do some settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
```

This only initializes the `WLResourceRequest` object. You have to call `resourceRequest.send()` to actually call the server.

```
alert("Calling adapter");                //printed
var url = "/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed1";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);

resourceRequest.send().then(onSuccess,onFailure); 
// Move the below line to your onSuccess.
// Add similar error handling in the onFailure
alert("Called adapter");                 //Not Printed
```

Comment: I have including resourceRequest.send(). it does not work. alert("Calling MsgA");                //printed
var url = "/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed1";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
alert("Called adapter");                 //Not Printed     For above code, during execution it will print alert("Calling MsgA"); then it has to execute next line WLResourceRequest and then it should print alert("Called MsgB");                             The problem is, it is not going to line alert("Called MsgB");  Please let me know why WL methods not 
working.

Comment: Can you share a sample project